# CommandFailedError when running systrace on Android 6.0 device

Tags: android, python-2.7, systrace

I want to capture a system trace, using the systrace tool.

I have this device (not-rooted) :
Pixi 4.5 Alcatel
Android 6.0 (API 23)

And I use Android Studio 4.2.2 and I have installed Python 2.7.18, as required (the version 3+ does not match).

Here is the command line to view the list of available categories on my device :

`C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace>C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python27\python systrace.py -l`

I chose this command with the -l option for my here question because it results (see below) in the expected list plus an extra set of lines which suggests that the error **CommandFailedError** is related to an exception on **HasRoot** :

```
       gfx - Graphics

       input - Input

        view - View System

     webview - WebView

          wm - Window Manager

          am - Activity Manager

          sm - Sync Manager

       audio - Audio

       video - Video

      camera - Camera

         hal - Hardware Modules

         app - Application

         res - Resource Loading

      dalvik - Dalvik VM

          rs - RenderScript

        hwui - HWUI

        perf - Performance

      bionic - Bionic C Library

       power - Power Management

       sched - CPU Scheduling

        freq - CPU Frequency

        idle - CPU Idle

        load - CPU Load

CRITICAL:root:(TimeoutThread-1-for-MainThread) Exception on HasRoot(myDeviceId, retries=3, timeout=30), attempt 1 of 4: CommandFailedError("(device: myDeviceId) one line of output was expected, but got: ['uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcar
d_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0', '']",)
CRITICAL:root:(TimeoutThread-2-for-MainThread) Exception on HasRoot(myDeviceId, retries=3, timeout=30), attempt 2 of 4: CommandFailedError("(device: myDeviceId) one line of output was expected, but got: ['uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcar
d_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0', '']",)
CRITICAL:root:(TimeoutThread-3-for-MainThread) Exception on HasRoot(myDeviceId, retries=3, timeout=30), attempt 3 of 4: CommandFailedError("(device: myDeviceId) one line of output was expected, but got: ['uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcar
d_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0', '']",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 49, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_systrace.main())
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py", line 205, in main
    main_impl(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py", line 177, in main_impl
    atrace_agent.list_categories(options)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\tracing_agents\atrace_agent.py", line 65, in list_categories
    if not devutils.HasRoot():
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 63, in timeout_r
etry_wrapper
    impl, timeout, retries, desc=desc, retry_if_func=retry_if_func)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\timeout_retry.py", line 164, in Run
    error_log_func=error_log_func)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 199, in JoinA
ll
    self._JoinAll(watcher, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 171, in _Join
All
    thread.ReraiseIfException()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 94, in run
    self._ret = self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\timeout_retry.py", line 156, in <lambda
>
    lambda: func(*args, **kwargs), name=thread_name)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 51, in impl
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\device_utils.py", line 562, in HasRoo
t
    output = self.RunShellCommand(['id'], single_line=True)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 56, in timeout_r
etry_wrapper
    return impl()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 51, in impl
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\device_utils.py", line 1556, in RunSh
ellCommand
    raise device_errors.CommandFailedError(msg % output, str(self))
devil.android.device_errors.CommandFailedError: (device: myDeviceId) one line of output was expected, but got: ['uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(
shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0', '']
```

By comparison, here is the error **CommandFailedError** obtained with a command which should generate an html report :

```
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace>C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python27\python systrace.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 49, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_systrace.main())
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py", line 205, in main
    main_impl(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\run_systrace.py", line 185, in main_impl
    controller.StartTracing()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\systrace_runner.py", line 46, in StartTracing
    self._tracing_controller.StartTracing()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\tracing_controller.py", line 156, in StartTracing
    timeout=self._controller_config.timeout):
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\common\py_utils\py_utils\__init__.py", line 103, in RunWithTimeout
    return timeout_retry.Run(func, timeout, 0, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\timeout_retry.py", line 164, in Run
    error_log_func=error_log_func)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 199, in JoinA
ll
    self._JoinAll(watcher, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 171, in _Join
All
    thread.ReraiseIfException()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\reraiser_thread.py", line 94, in run
    self._ret = self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\utils\timeout_retry.py", line 156, in <lambda
>
    lambda: func(*args, **kwargs), name=thread_name)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\tracing_agents\android_cgroup_agent.py", line 59, in StartAgent
Tracing
    if not self._device_utils.HasRoot():
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 56, in timeout_r
etry_wrapper
    return impl()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 51, in impl
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\device_utils.py", line 562, in HasRoo
t
    output = self.RunShellCommand(['id'], single_line=True)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 56, in timeout_r
etry_wrapper
    return impl()
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\decorators.py", line 51, in impl
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\systrace\catapult\systrace\systrace\..\..\devil\devil\android\device_utils.py", line 1556, in RunSh
ellCommand
    raise device_errors.CommandFailedError(msg % output, str(self))
devil.android.device_errors.CommandFailedError: (device: deviceId) one line of output was expected, but got: ['uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(
shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:shell:s0', '']
```

I am sure that there is a proper way to run systrace on an old unrooted device but I just didn't find it.

Does anyone have a clue or a solution? Thanks.

EDIT :

Thanks a lot for your analysis and your answer @yi-yang.

As you recommended, I set single_line to False in the RunShellCommand call. Furthermore, I also modified the return line, which gives the final code in the device_utils.py file, lines 562-563 :

```
output = self.RunShellCommand(['id'], single_line=False)
return output[0].startswith('uid=0(root)')
```

Note that I select the first line because there are still two lines, which means that some optional newline at the end needs to be stripped somehow...

Now it works but only for a few categories, as in the following example:

```
systrace.py -o mynewtrace.html perf idle load
```

However, for any atrace data, including the very helpful "sched" (see atrace_agent.py), the cpu profiling not possible, as shown by the following messages:

```
Warning: Only 2 of 3 tracing agents started.
IOError('Unable to get atrace data. Did you forget adb root?')
```

So the root privileges do matter, despite what the file comments (l. 556-558) claim :-(.
I guess **rooting** is a must for the full experience!

Comment: Looking at the code in device_utils.py, I think it runs the `id` shell command and uses the output to determine if the device "has root". It expects one line but on your device it outputs two, the first being 'uid=2000(shell)...' and the second an empty string. I just ran `adb shell id` on my Pixel 4 and it only returns one line. It might be a bug in the OEM implementation. Can you try editing Line 1556 in device_utils.py to `self.RunShellCommand(['id'], single_line=False)` and see if it works around the bug?

Comment: Yeah it's just the Python code didn't expect a second empty line. So if you can modify the code to get around that, the command should work on that device.

Comment: Thanks. I started a new comment and deleted it : see my EDIT above.

Comment: They shouldn't require root unless the OEM chose to override the default behavior. What's the output of `systrace -l` after you modified the script?